# Magento 1 - How to exclude column data from export csv file?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, importexport

I want to exclude Email and Billing Telephone columns data from orders export csv file for specific user. I am using Rave Infosys Order Import / Export extension.
These columns data should be empty for specific user.

Thanks